# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute??? I'm lost

Tags: python, class, exception, import, module

Ok so here is code from my module called Enemy.py:

```
from livewires import games, color
import random
import Cans



class Chef(games.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,pic,y = 55, speed = 2, odds_change = 200):
        super(Chef, self).__init__(image = pic,
                                   x = games.screen.width / 2,
                                   y = y,
                                   dx = speed)
        self.odds_change = odds_change
        self.time_til_drop = 0
        self.pizza = []
        self.i = 0
```

Now in my main program called TheGame.py I have this code:

```
from livewires import games, color
import random
import PersonPlayer
import Cans
import Enemy

games.init(screen_width = 1280, screen_height = 720, fps = 50)
games.music.load("Sound/NowWeDance.mp3")
wall_image = games.load_image("lacrosse.jpg", transparent = False)
games.mouse.is_visible = False
games.screen.event_grab = True
chefimg = games.load_image("Sprites/chef.bmp")
manlhimg = games.load_image("Sprites/manlh.bmp")




def main():

    games.music.play()
    games.screen.background = wall_image
    the_chef = Enemy.Chef(chefimg)
    games.screen.add(the_chef)

    the_hand = Hand(the_chef)
    games.screen.add(the_hand)

    games.screen.mainloop()



main()
```

When I try to run it I get this error (and other similar ones to it from other imported classes):

```
     File "C:\Users\Admin\workspace\Catcher\src\TheGame.py", line 28, in main
  the_chef = Enemy.Chef(chefimg)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Chef'
```

My Enemy module does have the attribute Chef and I'm totally confused as to why I am getting this error someone please help!

Comment: Do you have multiple Enemy modules...perhaps another one earlier on in your path?

Comment: Nope, it's the only one in my path, I am also using PyDev with Eclipse, but I ran into this same problem when using IDLE.  I'm wondering if it has something to do with the livewires modules

Comment: I am not convinced the body of the `Chef` class is not relevant to the question. Can you post it? At a minimum, the `__init__()` method.

Comment: if you opened a command prompt at: `C:\Users\Admin\workspace\Catcher\src\` (assuming that's the location of Enemy.py), ran python, and then did an: "from Enemy import Chef", does that work?

Comment: `class Chef(games.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,pic,y = 55, speed = 2, odds_change = 200):
       super(Chef, self).__init__(image = pic,
                                   x = games.screen.width / 2,
                                   y = y,
                                   dx = speed)
        self.odds_change = odds_change
        self.time_til_drop = 0
        self.pizza = []
        self.i = 0`

Comment: @Gerrat No it does not.

Comment: Then that is your problem.  You likely have some sort of error in your Enemy.py file.  You should edit your question and post the `Chef` class and (at least) it's init...the code-in-comment isn't too helpful.

Comment: I changed it, and even when I try to make a method to create and instance of the class, Eclipse says the method doesnt exist..

Comment: Does even "import Enemy" from command prompt -> python work?  Are you sure that what you're looking at in your editor is saved?

Comment: what you get when you do `print dir(Enemy)`?